# HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

When I run my project as android application, I get this:

```
[2014-02-06 10:25:36 - Emulator] HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
[2014-02-06 10:25:53 - HelloAbsoluteBeginner] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-02-06 10:25:53 - HelloAbsoluteBeginner] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

How to fix the error HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode, when I have AMD Athlon(tm) processor.

Comment: Do you have installed the Intel HAXM software? It is required by the emulator for running in HAX mode.

Comment: Intel HAXM is specifically for processors made by Intel. He is using AMD Athlon processor.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware Accelerated Emulation is available on processors which do support Virtualization technology. For that, your processor must need to comply either of the following:

- Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx) extensions
- AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (only supported for Linux)

There might be a possibility that this feature is disabled in your BIOS. Verify if your Athlon processor does support this instruction-set, check your BIOS settings and (in case of AMD processor) run your emulator in a Linux environment.

For more info, read [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html).